# How to create new row with Bootstrap and PHP?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have kind of an interesting problem. I am trying to create a grid style layout for a product page. I am using PHP and bootstrap to do this, but the issue I am having is everything stays on one row instead of creating a new row after 4 items are added to the grid. I have tried different looping styles with no luck, can anyone give any advice on this?

The grid should look like this

___ Item1 ___Item2 ___Item3 ___Item4____ <---- this is where a new row should start.

Here is my code:

```
while($temp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-1"> </div>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo '<form action="#" method="POST">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-2">';
        echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
        echo '<img src="', $row["pictureURL"], '">';
        echo '<div class="caption">';
        echo '<h4 class="pull-right">';
        echo '</h4>';
        echo '<h4><a href="productDetails.html">', $row[number], '</a></h4>';
        echo '<p>', $row[description], '</p>';
        echo '<p>Price: $', $row[price],'</p>';
        echo '<p><input type="submit" name="add" value="Add To Cart"></p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have something move to the next row after four `<div class="col-md-2">` are written?

Comment: Yes, so I have col-md-1 to pad the front, then after four col-md-2 (These are the items) I would like to start a new row.

Comment: Why not use `col-md-3` for your items instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%` ([Modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)) operator in your while. For each 4 rows, it should enter the `if` condition:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($i%4 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="col-md-1"> </div>';
    }
    echo '<form action="#" method="POST">';
    ....
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This code worked for the formatting so thanks you! I am having an issue now where the columns look like they are expanding while you go down the page. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by expanding?

Comment: So I have roughly 150 entries that I am displaying on one page, and as you scroll down, the rows are getting wider and wider. It's almost like they are somehow breaking out of the container or the container is getting wider itself. I am using col-md-3 now for the spacing because it's simpler.

Comment: Bootstrap rows have a size of `12` in grid system. So, all you need to do is to sum all `col-md-X` to 12, for each row. If you have 4 items, just use `col-md-3` in each one. If you have 5, you can use 3 with `col-md-3`, one with `col-md-2` and one with `col-md-1`.

Comment: Yea, I understand the grid system, but I have never seen bootstrap do this before. When I go to inspect the elements, they still show up as col-md-3, but they are way too wide to be that.